# How to select all checkboxes with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox, css-selectors

I need help with jQuery selectors. Say I have a markup as shown below:

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="select_all" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

How to get all checkboxes except `#select_all` when user clicks on it?

Comment: here is a link to codepen with this https://codepen.io/nickhq/pen/pZJVEr

Answer (score 115, accepted):

A more complete example that should work in your case:

```js
$('#select_all').change(function() {
  var checkboxes = $(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox');
  checkboxes.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="select_all" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

When the `#select_all` checkbox is clicked, the status of the checkbox is checked and all the checkboxes in the current form are set to the same status.

Note that you don't need to exclude the `#select_all` checkbox from the selection as that will have the same status as all the others. If you for some reason do need to exclude the `#select_all`, you can use this:

```js
$('#select_all').change(function() {
  var checkboxes = $(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox').not($(this));
  checkboxes.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="select_all" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: For me this only worked the first time (ie, check all, uncheck all).  On the second 'check all' none of the other checkboxes were checked.  I used `checkboxes.prop('checked', true);` and `checkboxes.prop('checked', false);` instead, from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15266603/1438809).  Oops, just realised this is mentioned in answers further down the page...

Comment: [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) states that `$( "[type=checkbox]" )` is faster for modern browsers (faster than `$(':checkbox')`).

Answer (score 54):

Simple and clean:

```js
$('#select_all').click(function() {
  var c = this.checked;
  $(':checkbox').prop('checked', c);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="select_all" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: this may also done like this...`$(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);`

Comment: Subtle - set the checked status of the retrieved checkboxes equal to that of our recently modified 'master' checkbox - simple, elegant and surprisingly logical when you think about it - Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

Top answer will not work in Jquery 1.9+ because of attr() method. Use prop() instead:

```
$(function() {
    $('#select_all').change(function(){
        var checkboxes = $(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox');
        if($(this).prop('checked')) {
          checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
        } else {
          checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I used your implementation with JQuery 1.8.3 ;-)

Comment: The OP modified the answer to cope with "recent" changes :)

Answer (score 21):

```
$("form input[type='checkbox']").attr( "checked" , true );
```

or you can use the

**[:checkbox Selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)**

```
$("form input:checkbox").attr( "checked" , true );
```

I have rewritten your HTML and provided a click handler for the main checkbox

```
$(function(){
    $("#select_all").click( function() {
        $("#frm1 input[type='checkbox'].child").attr( "checked", $(this).attr("checked" ) );
    });
});

<form id="frm1">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="select_all" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="select[]" class="child" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="select[]" class="child" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="select[]" class="child" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Just beware to don't check every checkbox on the page... :)

Comment: Actually, the correct syntax is `.attr("checked", "checked")`.

Comment: +1 Thanks rahul, but I needed to find all checkboxes when user clicks on #select_all checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $(function() {  
$('#select_all').click(function() {
    var checkboxes = $(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        checkboxes.attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        checkboxes.removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select_all").click(function(){
      var checked_status = this.checked;
      $("input[name='select[]']").each(function(){
        this.checked = checked_status;
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.select-all').on('change', function () {
            if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
                jQuery('input.class-name').each(function () {
                    this.checked = true;
                });
            } else {
                jQuery('input.class-name').each(function () {
                    this.checked = false;
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Code is great, but some explanation of why any how it helps is always welcome.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#select_all").change(function () {

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));

});
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 2):

This code works fine with me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#select_all").change(function(){
  $(".checkbox_class").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
  });
});
</script>
```

you only need to add class **checkbox_class** to all checkbox

Easy and simple :D

Answer (score 1):

Faced with the problem, none of the above answers do not work. The reason was in jQuery Uniform plugin (work with [theme metronic](http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_1/)).I hope the answer will be useful :)

> Work with **jQuery Uniform**

```
$('#select-all').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $checkboxes = $this.closest('form')
        .find(':checkbox');

    $checkboxes.prop('checked', $this.is(':checked'))
        .not($this)
        .change();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> *One checkbox to rule them all*

For people still looking for plugin to control checkboxes through one that's lightweight, has out-of-the-box support for UniformJS and iCheck and gets unchecked when at least one of controlled checkboxes is unchecked (and gets checked when all controlled checkboxes are checked of course) I've created a [jQuery checkAll plugin](https://github.com/simivar/jquery-checkall).

Feel free to check the examples on [documentation page](http://simivar.github.io/jquery-checkall/).

---

For this question example all you need to do is:

```
$( '#select_all' ).checkall({
    target: 'input[type="checkbox"][name="select"]'
});
```

Isn't that clear and simple?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.checkall').change(function() {
    var checkboxes = $(this).closest('table').find('td').find(':checkbox');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        checkboxes.attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        checkboxes.removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#select_all").live("click", function(){
            $("input").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
    }
  });
```

Comment: Add some explanation/commentary

Answer (score 0):

I'm now partial to this style.

I've named your form, and added an 'onClick' to your select_all box.

I've also excluded the 'select_all' checkbox from the jquery selector to keep the internet from blowing up when someone clicks it.

```
 function toggleSelect(formname) {
   // select the form with the name 'formname', 
   // then all the checkboxes named 'select[]'
   // then 'click' them
   $('form[name='+formname+'] :checkbox[name="select[]"]').click()
 }
```

---

```
 <form name="myform">
   <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="select_all"    
                   onClick="toggleSelect('myform')" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="select[]"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic jQuery plugin I wrote that selects all checkboxes on the page, except the checkbox/element that is to be used as the toggle:

```
(function($) {
    // Checkbox toggle function for selecting all checkboxes on the page
    $.fn.toggleCheckboxes = function() {
        // Get all checkbox elements
        checkboxes = $(':checkbox').not(this);

        // Check if the checkboxes are checked/unchecked and if so uncheck/check them
        if(this.is(':checked')) {
            checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
        }
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Then simply call the function on your checkbox or button element:

```
// Check all checkboxes
$('.check-all').change(function() {
    $(this).toggleCheckboxes();
});
```