# jQuery - toggle select all checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Fought with a bunch of examples and, being still new to jQuery/Javascript, cannot get my code to function (here my my template in gsp):

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
       <th><input type="checkbox" name="selectAll" onclick="selectAll(this.checked);"/></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="domainList" value="${domainInstance.id}"/></td>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

I have the following javascript snippet in my main gsp, that calls the template:

```
function selectAll(status) {

}
```

How do I select all checkboxes from the selectAll name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228382/select-all-checkboxes-with-jquery ?

Comment: `$(':input:checkbox[name="selectAll"]').prop('checked', true)` Bind it to the checkboxes change event and add some conditions

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, you should use an `onclick` handler like below for selectAll.

```
$(':checkbox[name=selectAll]').click (function () {
  $(':checkbox[name=domainList]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Please note that the above code is going to look into the entire dom for the checkbox with `name=selectAll` and set the status of the checkbox with `name=domainList`.

Below is a slightly better version with minor markup change,

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/F8HvX/)

```js
$('#selectAllDomainList').click(function() {
  var checkedStatus = this.checked;
  $('#domainTable tbody tr').find('td:first :checkbox').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', checkedStatus);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="domainTable">
  <!-- Added ID -->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <!-- Added ID to below select box -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectAll" id="selectAllDomainList" />
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="domainList" value="${domainInstance.id}" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="domainList" value="${domainInstance.id}" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="domainList" value="${domainInstance.id}" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="domainList" value="${domainInstance.id}" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <table>
```

Comment: This method is the way to go - unobtrusive JavaScript.  Ryan, if you use this method, be sure to take the onclick attribute out of your selectAll input.

Answer (score 7):

```
$("input:checkbox").prop("checked", status);
```

Answer (score 2):

to select  all checkboxes with name = selectAll and set their status you can do

```
function selectAll(status) {
   $('input[name=selectAll]').each(function(){
      $(this).prop('checked', status);
   });
}
```