# Check radio button when clicking it's div-container

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I wrote this simple script, and it's seems to work fine, but only once. I click div-container - the radio within gets checked. I click another div - another radio gets checked. But now, when I click the previous div again, the radio won't get checked.

Here's the code:

```
$('div').click(function () {
   $(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
});
```

And example: http://jsfiddle.net/aa7q6Lxy/1/

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: use .prop() instead of .attr() - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aa7q6Lxy/3/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266533/jquery-attrchecked-checked-works-only-once

Comment: please  check the all references are working or not .i think some reference is missing or not working