# Adding a select all checkbox in the SQLFORM.grid table header

Tags: checkbox, web2py, selectall

I found the code in google groups posted by Massimo Di Pierro:

```
<button onclick="jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(k){jQuery(this).attr('checked', 'checked');});">select all</button>
```

I create this question because based on previous question that I post here, what if I retrieve a record from the Student Master List that reach 500+ or 1000+ and the table I create has no Select All button? it's hard to click and click and click and so on... anyone know where I will put that code? so that it's easy to retrieve record if the table has a select all checkbox on it.

Comment: You need checkbox which will mark all checkboxes of grid when clicked on it. Right? Can you elaborate your question?

Answer (score 1):

With

```
form = SQLFORM.smartgrid(..,selectable= lambda ids: your_function_name_to_trigger(ids),...),
```

add this to your controller function:

```
if form.elements('th'):
    form.elements('th')[0].append(SPAN('All', BR(), INPUT(_type='checkbox',
        _onclick="jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(k{jQuery(this)
            .attr('checked', 'checked'));});")))
```

This will 'check' all of the checkboxes in the form when clicking on the all button.

Comment: The code you pasted has some errors, but the idea works. I used the js code on the question but the idea here and it does what's needed

Answer (score 0):

Place the above code anywhere in the view where you want the button to be visible. It will find all checkboxes on the page.

Comment: thanks for the reply Remco... I will try it later... Thanks also for the reply Gaura Vichare I think Remco solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

I combined Serge answer with [Jquery Checkbox check all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537609/jquery-checkbox-check-all) solution, and works well:

```
if form.elements('th'):
    form.elements('th')[0].append(SPAN('All', BR(), INPUT(_type='checkbox',
    _onclick="jQuery('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);"
    )))
```