# Checking state of checkbox nested inside an a tag, nested inside a li, inside a ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to make a select all for a set of checkboxes in a ul.  I have successfully made a toggle but a toggle isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="filter">
    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />Test 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />Test 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the starting of the click function that I'm using to manipulate the page based off of the checkboxes

```
$('#filter >li>a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $target = $(event.currentTarget),
    val = $target.attr('data-value'),
    $inp = $target.find('input'),
    idx;
```

From here I'm trying to make an if statement to check whether or not select all (in sample code `test1`) is selected and whether or not it's checked so that the code can then check or uncheck all other checkboxes.

Comment: Is there a reason for using an `anchor` as opposed to a label?

Comment: I don't think so.  It's just the format I found first for doing this kind of set up.  Do you think it makes a difference?

Comment: Yeah, it does for Accessibility reasons. Screen readers will read this as a label rather than a link

Comment: Okay that's fair.  I'm currently not concerned with accessibility, though that's a good note for going forward!  Thank you @OluwafemiSule

Comment: If you want to treat a particular element specially, like a Select All checkbox, give it a distinct ID or class, and bind a handler to that ID/class. Then use `:not()` to exclude that element from the general handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="filter">
    <li><a onclick="for(i=1;i<document.
querySelectorAll('#filter a input').length;i++){document.
querySelectorAll('#filter a input')[i].checked=document.
querySelectorAll('#filter a input')[0].checked;}" href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" id="test1" /><label for="test1">Test 1</label></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" id="test2" /><label for="test2">Test 2</label></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" id="test3" /><label for="test3">Test 3</label></a></li>
</ul>
```

From this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18537624/6917520

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ayunami2000/z5x4pxk2/3/

Answer (score 0):

Check the value for input to see if it's the first option.
If it is, select all input in the dropdown menu and have them checked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#filter >li>a').on('click',
    function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var $target = $(event.currentTarget),
        val = $target.attr('data-value'),
        $inp = $target.find('input'),
        idx;
   
      var isChecked = !$inp.prop('checked');
      if(val == 'option1') {
       $('.dropdown-menu input').prop('checked', isChecked);
      } else {
         $inp.prop('checked', isChecked);
      }
      
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="filter">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1">
      <input type="checkbox">Test 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1">
      <input type="checkbox">Test 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1">
      <input type="checkbox">Test 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```