# Many checkbox groups and "select all"

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have 8 groups of checkboxes. Each with a "master" and between 8 and 12 sub-checkboxes and try to create a "un/select all" behaviour to each group.

I found this SO
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25697142/9098325 but it only shows one group of checkboxes.

I made a fiddle with my not working solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/ex4rnq83/

```js
$('.outer').on('click', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.inner').each(function() {
      this.checked = true;
    });
  } else {
    $('.inner').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
  }
});

$('.inner').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    var isAllChecked = 0;

    $(".inner").each(function() {
      if (!this.checked)
        isAllChecked = 1;
    });

    if (isAllChecked == 0) {
      $(".outer").prop("checked", true);
    }
  } else {
    $(".outer").prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="out1" class="outer">
    <label for="out1">Checkbox Out 1</label>
  </li>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="inner1" class="inner">
      <label for="out1">Checkbox Inner 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="inner2" class="inner">
      <label for="out1">Checkbox Inner 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="inner3" class="inner">
      <label for="out1">Checkbox Inner 3</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="out2" class="outer">
    <label for="out1">Checkbox Out 2</label>
  </li>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="inner4" class="inner">
      <label for="out1">Checkbox Inner 4</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="inner5" class="inner">
      <label for="out1">Checkbox Inner 5</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have a look at closest and next().children()

Comment: use `data-id` attribute and check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly if you correct the HTML so that the child `ul` are within the `li` of the parent, then this becomes much simpler. When a checkbox is checked you can easily traverse the DOM to find child checkboxes and set their `checked` state to match.

Similarly, you can get the checked state of sibling checkboxes. If they are all checked then any parent checkbox should be checked. Something like this:

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  // check children
  $(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);

  // check parent if all children checked
  var $ul = $(this).closest('ul');
  var $siblings = $ul.find('> li > label > :checkbox');
  var allChecked = $siblings.length == $siblings.filter(':checked').length;
  $ul.closest('li').find('> label > :checkbox').prop('checked', allChecked);
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Checkbox Out 1</label>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox">Checkbox Inner 1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox">Checkbox Inner 2</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox">Checkbox Inner 3</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Checkbox Out 2</label>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox">Checkbox Inner 4</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox">Checkbox Inner 5</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note this completely negates the need for any unique `id` attributes, as the logic relies on the DOM structure and the `label` elements have been moved to wrap the checkbox they are related to. The `inner` and `outer` class attributes have also been removed as they become redundant when nesting the `ul`/`li` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example

It toggles the children of the next UL and toggles the outer checkbox if all or less than all children are checked

I corrected the invalid HTML to have the ULs as children of the LI and not another UL

```js
$('.outer').on('click', function() {
  var chk = this.checked;
  $(this).closest("li").find(".inner").each(function() {
    this.checked = chk;
  });
});

$('.inner').on('click', function() {
  var $parent = $(this).closest("ul"),
    $inner = $parent.find(".inner"),
    $checked = $parent.find(".inner:checked"),
    $outer = $parent.closest("li").find(".outer"),
    chk = $inner.length === $checked.length ? this.checked : false;
  $outer.prop("checked", chk)
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="out1" class="outer"><label for="out1">Checkbox Out 1</label>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="inner1" class="inner"><label for="out1">Checkbox Inner 1</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="inner2" class="inner"><label for="out1">Checkbox Inner 2</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="inner3" class="inner"><label for="out1">Checkbox Inner 3</label></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="out2" class="outer"><label for="out1">Checkbox Out 2</label>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="inner4" class="inner"><label for="out1">Checkbox Inner 4</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="inner5" class="inner"><label for="out1">Checkbox Inner 5</label></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This answers my question to 100 percent, but I chose @Rory McCrossan answer, because it is more sophisticated. I hope you understand. :)

Comment: Sure. Mine made as little changes to the html as possible. That is more or less the only difference, He has to travers the label now too. And the filter is unnecessary in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

I modified your question with a working one.

Just replace `$(".inner").each` with `$(this).parent().next().find('li input').each` or another correct selector.

```js
$('.outer').on('click', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).parent().next().find('li input').each(function() {
      this.checked = true;
    });
  } else {
    $(this).parent().next().find('li input').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
  }
});

$('.inner').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    var isAllChecked = 0;

    $(".inner").each(function() {
      if (!this.checked)
        isAllChecked = 1;
    });

    if (isAllChecked == 0) {
      $(".outer").prop("checked", true);
    }
  } else {
    $(".outer").prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="out1" class="outer">
    <label for="out1">Checkbox Out 1</label>
  </li>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="inner1" class="inner">
      <label for="out1">Checkbox Inner 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="inner2" class="inner">
      <label for="out1">Checkbox Inner 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="inner3" class="inner">
      <label for="out1">Checkbox Inner 3</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="out2" class="outer">
    <label for="out1">Checkbox Out 2</label>
  </li>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="inner4" class="inner">
      <label for="out1">Checkbox Inner 4</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="inner5" class="inner">
      <label for="out1">Checkbox Inner 5</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$('.outer').on('click', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.inner').each(function() {
      this.checked = true;
    });
  } else {
    $('.inner').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
  }
});
```

to this:

```
$('.outer').on('click',function(){
    if(this.checked){

        $(this).parent().next("ul").children('li').children('.inner').each(function(){
            this.checked = true;
        });
  }else{
        $(this).parent().next("ul").children('li').children('.inner').each(function(){
            this.checked = false;
    });
  }
});
```

jquery will first select parent then next ul and then all inputs with 'inner' class.

alse change end part of your js code to this:

```
    $('.inner').on('click',function(){
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var isAllChecked = 0;

            $(this).parent().parent().children('li').children('.inner').each(function() {
                if (!this.checked)
                    isAllChecked = 1;
            });

            if (isAllChecked == 0) {
                $(this).parent().parent().prev('li').children('.outer').prop("checked", true);
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log()
            $(this).parent().parent().prev('li').children('.outer').prop("checked", false);
        }
```

it will select outer input before your inner classes

Comment: This does not uncheck the parent if not all children are checked like mine does

Comment: Thats working! Do you know how it can be done if I check every sub-checkbox the master-checkbox is also checked?

Comment: i put it on fiddle . check it : https://jsfiddle.net/ex4rnq83/ . it works perfectly

Comment: Please post the solution in a stacksnippet here, like I showed you. Just click the `[<>]` snippet editor button

Comment: oh, could you please provide more information.what does is do?