# how to make a check all checkbox using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm looking for is when I check "all" all other elements are checked and when I uncheck it all others are unchecked.

```js
$(".dropdown dt a").on('click', function() {
  $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
});

$(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function() {
  $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});

function getSelectedValue(id) {
  return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
}

$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  var $clicked = $(e.target);
  if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});

$('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {

  var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
    title = $(this).val() + " ";

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
    $('.multiSel').append(html);
    $(".hida").hide();
  } else {
    $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
    var ret = $(".hida");
    $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="dropdown">
  <dt>
    <a>
      <span class="hida">Choisir :</span>
      <p class="multiSel"></p>
    </a>
    </dt>
  <dd>
    <div class="mutliSelect">
      <ul>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="ALL" value="All"> All</li>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="val1">val1</li>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="val2">val2</li>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="val3">val3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8kwb54md/1/

Comment: Show the HTML that this is meant to operate on.

Comment: @connexo check the full code buddy

Comment: _"Why doesn't my code work?"_ requires a [mcve] which shows the actual problem **in the question itself** and not only a link to an external resource.

Comment: @Andreas sorry for that but HTML + CSS + Jquery  code is 140 lines and cann't post it all in here !!

Comment: That's why we require a **minimal** example. Strip anything that isn't related to the problem. And as you can see on my edit it is absolutely possible to supply such a minimal example...

Comment: @Andreas tanks buddy thats amazing !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select all checkboxes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228382/select-all-checkboxes-with-jquery)

Comment: @Baldráni Please don't edit code in questions that radically; it makes the answers irrelevant.

Comment: How is it making the answers irrelevants since they all still worked. I just removed code which is not in direct relation with the question. I don't get your point there :/ @HereticMonkey

Comment: @issam: (probably) irrelevant to your problem, but why are you declaring the `title` variable twice, and to different values?

Comment: @Baldráni Just don't edit code in questions. See the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245). Post a comment and the OP can edit their own code. This is especially true when you have an answer on the question to avoid the appearance of doing something to make your own answer look better.

Answer (score 2):

I reduced your HTML to the list with the checkboxes:

```js
document.querySelector('[name=ALL]').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  let checkboxes = e.target.closest('ul').querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
  Array.from(checkboxes).forEach((cb) => {
    cb.checked = e.target.checked;
  });
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="ALL" value="All">All</li>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="val1">val1</li>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="val2">val2</li>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="val3">val3</li>
</ul>
```

If you insist on using jQuery, here you go:

```js
$('[name="ALL"]').on('change', function() {
  var self = this;
  $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    this.checked = self.checked;
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="ALL" value="All">All</li>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="val1">val1</li>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="val2">val2</li>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="val3">val3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @issam The StackOverflow way of saying "thanks" is upvoting.

Comment: oh ok but i can't cuz i'm below 15 lvl :)

Comment: @connexo The Stack Overflow way is to mark questions as duplicates, not answer them... :P

Comment: @HereticMonkey I like to add non-jquery answers to jquery questions, though :)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Here is a bit of help :

```js
$('[name="ALL"]').on('click', function(){
    $('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked') ?  $(this).prop('checked','') : $(this).prop('checked','checked')
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="mutliSelect">
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="ALL" value="All">All</li>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="val1">val1</li>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="val2">val2</li>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="val3">val3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And if he unchecks `ALL`?

Comment: The property checked is either `true` or `false`.

Comment: @Baldráni thanks dude it works perfectly but how about whene i uncheck "all" the rest are unchecked too

Comment: @connexo I'm sorry but I don't get your point with your remark

Comment: `$(this).prop('checked','')` is setting `HTMLInputElement.prototype.checked` which is a **boolean** property on the element to an empty string.

Comment: Check my answer to see how to do it cleanly using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".mutliSelect input:checkbox").first().click(function(){
    $('.mutliSelect input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

This code will select the first input checkbox, hook it to the click event, then it will check all the remaining checkboxs but not the first one, if the first checkbox is checked it will check them all otherwise uncheck them all.

Bon courage.

Comment: mrc c tres gentil ;)

Answer (score 0):

> We need to uncheck all checkbox if any of the options are unchecked.

```js
var checkBoxAll = $('ul li> input[name="ALL"]');
var checkBoxOptions = $('ul li> input:not([name="ALL"])');
checkBoxAll.on('change', function() {
  var self = this;
  $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    this.checked = self.checked;
  })
})

// to check or uncheck All checkbox, if all the options are checked.
checkBoxOptions.on('change', function() {
    var isAllChecked = true;
  
  // to find if any of the options is false.
  $(this).closest('ul').find('li> input:not([name="ALL"])').each(function() {
    if (!this.checked) return isAllChecked = false;
  })
  
  checkBoxAll.get(0).checked = isAllChecked;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="ALL" value="All">All</li>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="val1">val1</li>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="val2">val2</li>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="val3">val3</li>
</ul>
```